# My SQL installation Error in Linux Mint installation

Tags: mysql, linux, installation, linux-mint

Tried to install MYSQL in Linux mint. I got stuck up with this image after using the command `sudo apt install mysql-server`. I couldn't press OK to continue with the installation.

Can anyone please help me to proceed with this error?

[image]

Comment: Use TAB to select OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an error. This is just a message about configuring mysql-server. You need to press TAB, then select OK and finally press Enter to close it.